# unity how to keep prefabs updated

Tags: unity, workflow

I have a number of prefabs in unity and I regulary update them, is there an easy way make sure unity updates these prefabs so that I don't have to update 20+ identical objects in identical ways acros 10  different scenes?

Comment: If you update a prefab, and hit "Apply" it should do what you're asking.

Comment: Ah thanks now I know what that button does do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that was your problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changing prefabs, you have to hit the "Apply" button to commit the changes. This is the only part you're missing.